# How can I read from a list to get a dict?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am getting an error I have never seen before, and there isn't great information on the internet on how to fix this that I could understand.

```
embed.add_field(name=f"Departure Airport ({res['departure']['airport']['icao']})")
```

The Error:
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

JSON Response: https://mystb.in/NeverSmiliesTowers.json

I understand that I am trying to read the list as a dict, but I am not so sure how to get a dict from a list. Hope you understand my issue.

> Note: res is just res = await foo.json(). It just formats the response in JSON.
> I am also not reading this from a local file. I am reading this from an API response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a common misconception that JSONs always represent dictionaries at their top level. They can represent lists as well at the top level. These are both valid JSONs:

```
{
  "a": "foo",
  "b": ["bar", "baz"]
}
```

```
[
  {
    "a1": "foo1",
    "b1": ["bar1", "baz1"]
  },
  {
    "a2": "foo2",
    "b2": ["bar2", "baz2"]
  }
[
```

The JSON sample you provided matches the second snippet above, where the top-level structure is a list(-like). Notice how the JSON begins with an opening square-bracket:

```
[
   {
      "greatCircleDistance":{
        ...
```

The `res` JSON is a list of dictionaries, so you need to retrieve the first dictionary from this list.

You can do so with:

`res[0]['departure']['airport']['icao']`

(notice how we first index the `res` list, which returns a dictionary that we can then get the 'departure' from.)

Answer (score 1):

The response is a list, not a dict. You need to first access that list and then all the dict keys

```py
res[0]['departure']['airport']['icao']
```